# Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ differentiable such that $f(0)=0$ and for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ we have $f'(x)=(f(x))^2$. Show $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ differentiable such that $f(0)=0$ and for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ we have $f'(x)=(f(x))^2$. Show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Just a Hint!

What can i use to solve this problem?

Comment: I would keep derivating

Comment: @RobArthan You can, because $f'(x)=f(x)^2$ implies that $f'(x)$ is differentiable by chain rule

Answer (score 5):

Let $U = \{ x \in \Bbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \}$ be the set of zeros of $f$. Clearly $U$ is closed and non-empty. We claim that $U$ is also open. Since $\Bbb{R}$ is connected, this is possible only when $U = \Bbb{R}$.

To this end, let $a \in U$ and $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary and let $M = \sup_{|x-a| < \delta} |f(x)| $. Then by the mean value theorem, for $x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ we have

$$ |f(x)| = |f(x) - f(a)| \leq M^2|x - a| \leq M^2 \delta. $$

From this we have $M \leq M^2\delta$. If $\delta$ is sufficiently small, then we have $M\delta < 1$ and the previous inequality yields $M = 0$. This shows that $(a-\delta, a+\delta) \subseteq U$ and hence the claim follows.

Comment: Doesn't $M$ depend on $\delta$ ? So why should it hold that $M\delta<1$ when $\delta$ is small ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Although $M$ depends on $\delta$, the dependence is nice in the sense that $\delta \mapsto M(\delta)$ is increasing. So making $\delta$ small makes $M(\delta)$ small as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's immediate from the existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations.

If you don't have that, you might note that (if $f(x) \ne 0$) $\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{1}{f(x)} = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $x \ge 0$
$$f(x) = \int_0^x f(t)^2 dt$$
from the fundamental theorem of calculus and the fact that $f(0)=0$.
Note also that $f$ is increasing and positive for $x \ge 0$ (why?).
Hence for all $x \ge 0$,

$$f(x) \le xf(x)^2.$$

If $f(x)$ is not $0$ for some $0 \le y \le 1$, we can divide the above inequality by $f(y)$ to see that $f(y) \ge 1$. This is a contradiction (why? Hint: IVT). We can deduce that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1].$

From this we can deduce the following inequality:

$$f(x) \le (x-1)f(x)^2.$$

Applying the above logic inductively we can prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \ge 0$. (i.e suppose there is $1 \le y \le  2$ such that $f(y)$ is not $0$.....etc).

A similar argument works for $x<0$. This shows $f$ must be everywhere $0$.

Comment: You might want to write $f(x)=\int^x_0 f(t)^2\,dt$

Comment: Yup - cheers! :)